# preg_replace() Question

Tags: php, preg-replace

Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/m','<br>',$var);
```

to replace line ends with `<br>` elements. An example of what I want:

```
Text Text Text
Text Text Text

Text Text Text
```

Should end up being:

```
Text Text Text<br>Text Text Text<br><br>Text Text Text
```

This does what it needs to, but I'd like to recognize when there is a double space and add two breaklines, instead of a single one.  How can I do this, while retaining the current effect for single break lines?

I'm not too familiar with how preg_replace() works and I actually had to get help here to get that function in the first place.  I took a look in the PHP manual and the function seemed a little confusing.  Would anyone know of a site where I could learn how it works correctly?

Comment: So, what do you really want to achieve? Replace any newline in the `$var` with the `br`?

Comment: What is the encoding/charset of the text/string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [replace](http://php.net/str_replace) each end-of-line character with `<br />`:

```
$var = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), '<br />', $var);
```

There is no need to use a regular expression, but if you really want, you can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to achieve the same effect:

```
$var = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", '<br />', $var);
```

Comment: Only the preg_replace function works, but thats all I need.  Thanks.

Comment: @Phillip `str_replace` should work fine, too. Can you elaborate on "how it doesn't work"? On my system, `var_export(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), '<br />', "a\n\r\nb"));
` correctly outputs `'a<br /><br />b'`.

Comment: Its not including any `<br>` tags at all when using the `str_replace()` you provided.  It treats everything as a whitespace.

Comment: @Phillip I'm fairly certain both code fragments are exactly equivalent. In the interest of anyone else having the same problem, can you give a [short example that reproduces the problem](http://sscce.org/)? You can call [`export_var`](http://php.net/export_var) on `$var` to get php code for the input value.

Comment: On my system `var_export(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), '<br>', $var));` outputs 'Text Text Text Text' where `$var` is similar to my example in the question (can't show different lines here).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by adding the *g*-modifier to the preg_replace like so:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/mg','<br>',$var);
```

preg stands for Perl Regular Expression - you'll find a lot more examples with this search string, e.g. [this site](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html) or [this site](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm) (I'm actually unsure, what the *m*-modifier does?)

Alternatively, you could use the simple `$var = str_replace(' ', '<br', $var)`. I'm unsure, which one is faster.

**Edit:** If you want to replace newlines with html-breaks, use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

php has a built in function for this

```
echo nl2br( $var );
```

this does \n, \r\n, \r, and \n\r

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: There was actually something wrong with that function when I used it.  It was having some serious issues detecting double breaklines and I couldn't use it.  I may have implemented it wrong somehow (how I wouldn't know), but I had to go with the preg_replace option and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one. Not sure you are asking for that, but at least it works for me

```
$input = <<<DOC
Test Test Test
Test Test Test

Test Test Test
DOC;
$output = preg_replace("/$/m","<br/>",$input);
echo $output;
```

Hovewer, `nl2br` does just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you’re trying to do?

```
<?php
$text = <<<EndText
Text Text Text
Text Text Text

Text Text Text
EndText;

$text = str_replace("\r", "", $text);
$text = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $text);

echo $text;
?>
```